PostgreSQL custom session variable not set when executing in GCP Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL
In my server I am executing the following SQL before every operation executed against the DB:
SET SESSION audit.user_id = '${userId}';
SET SESSION audit.site_name = '${siteName}';

that aims to set two session variables that are used later on in an audit logging trigger like so:
create or replace function audit.audit_trigger()
 returns trigger
 language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
    v_user_id text;
    v_site_name text;
begin
    v_user_id := current_setting('audit.user_id', true);
    v_site_name := current_setting('audit.site_name', true);

   <persist audit log entry with the two variables>
end;
$function$;

When running locally against a local PostgreSQL everything works in order and in the audit log produced by the trigger I am seeing the variables that I have set with SET SESSION.
Unfortunately, when I deploy the same server code to GCP where it uses CloudSQL for PostgreSQL I am seeing empty the columns for the user_id and site_name in the audit logs produced by the trigger.
I have placed several logs ensuring that the SET SESSION commands are being ran successfully and do not return an error and they also set to the correct value.
Additionally I tried reproducing the problem with psql against the CloudSQL instance, where I tried the same sequence of commands:
SET SESSION audit.user_id = 'test'
UPDATE <some table> SET name = 'new value' WHERE id = 'id';

but now in the resulting audit log from the trigger that has been executed as a result from the UPDATE operation I am seeing the user_id as test
I was thinking whether it was some permission issues, but I made sure to log into psql with the same user that my server uses.
Also, CloudSQL seems like it supports this feature since it works from psql.
